# Indian Passport : Last Name missing and merged to Given name

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india

I have an Indian passport valid from (2015 to 2025) and I traveled with this many times in EUROPE before. The problem i am facing now after i move permanently to EUROPE and they given me a Resident Card here with an additional **"X"** in my name.

For e.g my full name(in all Indian documents) is "Abhinav Kumar" but i received my Resident Card in Europe as **"X Abhinav Kumar"**. After checking this with authorities in Europe, they told me this is due to my `Surname` is empty is my Indian Passport and only `Given name` column is there as **"Abhinav Kumar"**.

**PROBLEM :** So i backtracked the issue at my end and found that while filing for passport application form in 2015, I mistakenly put my `Last name` in `Given name` column(and kept last name blank). Thus my passport issued with `Given Name` as **"Abhinav Kumar"** and `Last name` as blank/empty.

**QUESTION :** Can i get new passport with correction of name without any additional document/Newspaper publications as Technically there are no change in my name. (its just wrongly entered in system). Also, can i do this name correction in tatkal service, as document advisor of Indian Passport online shows the name change are generally not in Tatkal service? Please advise.

Comment: Try to contact some authority (if your are in Europe, try a consular office, so to have a fix person/small team to discuss your case). I do not know India case, but it is about authority to make changes (independent of origin): you need to change the name in a DB, so fewer person have permission to do it (independent of the cause). Your case smell bureaucracy nightmares, so contact them, until you get to the right person (and so the problem solved). I'm not sure you can find an answer here. but also an answer from the first people you get in touch.

Comment: See [FAQ 49 on official site](https://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqServicesAvailable). It redirects to FAQ48. The crux is that you should verify particulars at the counter and if you find a mistake after passort is issued, you should approach Regional Passport office (RPO) immediately for rectification. If you are in India, you should contact the RPO for advice. If outside, the consulate would be able to guide you.